# Unable to pass inputtext value to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following input text

```
    <apex:inputText id="emailadd" value="{!Order__c.Email__c}">
</apex:inputText>
```

I have the controller

```
String toAddress = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('emailadd');
```

The toAddress in controller is returning null.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, save a reference to your object:

```
public class MyExt {
  Order__c record;
  public MyExt(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    record = sc.getRecord();
  }
  ...
```

Then, you can access it directly:

```
String toAddress = record.Email__c;
```

Using pageParameters is typically only for scenarios like checking the values in the query string or when using apex:param. You can't use it in the general case of binding to any arbitrary input (nor should you, as it's much easier to bind the input values directly).

Comment: This works. But is there a way that we have that defaulted, but on the fly if the user wanted to change the value in to address to something else. How can that be captured in controller?>

Comment: @user46620 Whatever the user puts in the field will be present in the record. There's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: So this is the issue that I was                                                                                   To: test@test.com  - This is the default value pulled from field value on VF page. Now if I want to change the value on vf page in to value, it is not sending email to the changed value, rather sending to the Object field value

Answer (score 0):

> getParameters() Returns a map of the query string parameters that are
>   included in the page URL. The key string contains the name of the
>   parameter, while the value string contains the value of the parameter.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm

To get the value of input text field you could use:

```
   <apex:inputText id="emailadd" value="{!var}">
</apex:inputText>
```

Controller / Extension :

```
public String var{get;set;}
```

The `variable` will store the value of what user inputs.

Comment: This works. But I would like to have a default value appearing on the vf page initially and then have the ability for user to change it if required. If I use the above code, the text field would be initially empty correct

Comment: Yes, In that case use what sfdcfox answered.